# How to split a string using . (period with space) as delimiter in JSTL

Tags: jsp, split, jstl

I am trying to split a string using . (period with space) but for some reason it does't work in JSTL

```
input: This is a sample text. Just to check the split.
```

The below statement splits the value using the period (.) as delimter works as expected,

```
<c:set var="descArray" value="${fn:split(desc_highlighted,'.')}"/>  
<c:forEach var="indexVal" items="${descArray}">
            <c:set var="descValue" value="${descValue} ${indexVal} ."/> 
</c:forEach 

output: This is a sample text. Just to check the split.
```

if I modify the statement to match period with space (. ), the sentence is getting split on each spacing

```
<c:set var="descArray" value="${fn:split(desc_highlighted,'. ')}"/> 
<c:forEach var="indexVal" items="${descArray}">
            <c:set var="descValue" value="${descValue} ${indexVal} ."/> 
</c:forEach

output: This . is . a . sample . text . Just . to . check . the . split .
```

Can someone let me know if I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the second argument to `fn:split()` works like an array of characters rather than a string.  So it's splitting on the period *or* the space, resulting in an array that's larger than you expected.  One way to handle this would be to use `fn:replace()` to replace all occurrences of `". "` with a single character.  Then pass the returned string to `fn:split()`.  This example uses a pipe.

```
<c:set var="descArray" 
       value="${fn:split(fn:replace(desc_highlighted, '. ', '|'),'|')}"/>
```